# How monit works?

Tags: monit

I need to know how monit monitoring tool works.I mean, do we need to install it on the server itself to which we will be monitoring or do we need to have monit installed on a seperate server to monitr all agents centrally like opeview?
Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Monit can perform remote check through ping or tcp/ucp connection (allowing also specification of predefined protocol, http(s), smtp etc..) or even custom scripts.

It can also monitor socket, process and for these, it has to be obviously local.

It up to your checks to decide.

In my case, I have local (to check process, pid network, cpu, etc..) + remote to ensure host services are accessible and working remotely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it to monitor server itself. If you have local system you can monitor that as well. If you want to monitor multiple server and view it's data at one place, then there is another tool called **M/Monit**.

You need to install **monit** on all servers you want to monitor and you can have **M/Monit** installed on one server which can be accessed from other server. You can configure monit server to send data to M/Monit server, from M/Monit server you can view data for all servers.

You can also set alerts (email) on some conditions, which **monit** or **M/Monit** will trigger to let you  know there is something wrong.